# Reversing items in a list

Tags: python

I have to reverse a list in Python, and I know that the method reverse() will do the job just fine.
However, I stumbled upon this piece of code which does the job as well, but I cannot understand it perfectly.

This the function which returns the list.

```
def reverse(list):
    for i in range(len(list) // 2):
        list[i], list[len(list) -i -1] =  list[len(list) -i -1], list[i] 

    return list
```

Why the loop goes through half of list's length here? Moreover, I don't understand the two commas in the third line.

Answer (score 6):

```
def reverse(list):
    for i in range(len(list) // 2):
        print('Swapping {} and {}'.format(i, len(list) -i -1))
        # list[i], list[len(list) -i -1] =  list[len(list) -i -1], list[i] 
    return list


reverse(range(9))
```

yields

```
Swapping 0 and 8
Swapping 1 and 7
Swapping 2 and 6
Swapping 3 and 5
```

That should give you an idea what the code is doing.

---

It helps to know that

```
a, b = b, a
```

swaps the values in the variables `a` and `b`. In an assignment [Python evaluates the right-hand side of the assignment first](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). Then assigns the values to the variables on the left-hand side.

So

```
list[i], list[len(list) -i -1] =  list[len(list) -i -1], list[i]
```

is swapping the values held in the `i` and `len(list)-i-1` index positions in the list.

---

By the way, naming a variable `list` is bad since it shadows the Python builtin of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

It is only going looping for half the list's length, but for each loop, it is moving TWO objects in the list.  It is using tuple packing/unpacking to swap two values in a single line of code.  Line three is essentially saying `a, b = b, a` which creates a tuple from `b` and `a`, then assigns the first member to `a` and the second member to `b`.  The end result is that `a` and `b` swap values without having to use 3 lines of code and a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to multiple elements on the left hand side of statements, provided that your right hand size returns multiple things. It might as well have been written like:

```
list[i] = list[len(list)-i-1]
list[len(list)-i-1] = list[i]
```

But the above would execute atomically. Sequentially of course the above does nothing, since it would require a temporary variable, thus the one-liner is a nice shortcut.

Logically, this is a swap. To reverse a list, simply swap an element with it's mirror with respect to the middle of the array, hence looping only up to `len(list)/2`

Answer (score 2):

You only need to go through half of the list because each time through you are swapping two items, starting with the first and last, then the second and second-to-last, and so on. So once you reach the middle item in the list, you are done. If you kept going, you would undo everything that you just did, swapping each of those items back.

For the line with the commas, it is basically just a shortcut to executing multiple assignments at once, but with the added benefit that the assignments are executed concurrently instead of sequentially, this means that things like:

```
a, b = b+1, a+1
```

will result in new values `a_new = b_old + 1` and `b_new = a_old + 1`, while operations like:

```
a = b+1
b = a+1
```

will result in values `a_new = b_old + 1` and `b_new = a_new + 1`. In the former case, the two statements are evaluated prior to assignment, while in the latter case each line is evaluated sequentially, so the value of `a` is changed before we use it to update the value of `b`.

For your swapping algorithm, you want to make sure to switch both values at the same time (concurrently) rather than sequentially. If you think about the first and last values this is obvious. By swapping concurrently, we get `first_new = last_old` and `last_new = first_old`. If we swapped sequentially we would have `first_new = last_old` and `last_new = first_new = last_old`, so our swap would not work.

**Edit:** An example from the [Python Tutorial where they use this notation can be found here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming).

Answer (score 1):

This only goes through half of the list because it is operating on two ends simultaneously. The comma operator in this case allows you to assign to multiple variables, and is working like this:

```
a,b = b,a # now a has b's value and b has a's value
```

that is what they are doing up there, so really the function starts with the first and last element, swaps them, then moves on to the second and penultimate element, and so on and so forth until there is nothing more to swap